# Firebase field delayed update

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a Firebase with a `users` reference, which has a field `user_id`.
(`[Firebase]/[app]/users/user_id`)

I insert a user & assign a user_id. However, when I read the value of user_id from userRef (a reference to `users`), it does not read it **the first time**. Subsequent reads work perfectly fine.

Using the debugger, I can see that when the user is created, a `user_id` is assigned. It seems like my first call refreshes the Firebase reference, so that subsequent calls are now seeing the udpated Firebase (I don't think that is what it is - that is just how it appears).

This is my code to read the value of `user_id`:

```
var userID = 0;
userRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    userID = snapshot.val().user_id;
});
alert(userID);
```

The first time, the alert shows `0`. Every time after that, it shows the correct value.

To make the problem even stranger, I also have a `games` reference with a `game_id`, created in the same way as `user`. But my read on `game_id` (in the exact same way & at the same time) works every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that .on() doesn't (in general) trigger your callback function immediately.  In particular, the first time you do a .on() at a location, Firebase has to go ask the server for the current value, wait for the response, and *THEN* call your callback.  And it does this all asynchronously.

The way your code is currently written, "alert(userID);" is being run before your callback code ("userID = snapshot.val().user_id;") so it always reports 0 the first time.  The simple fix is to move the alert() inside your callback:

```
var userID = 0;
userRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    userID = snapshot.val().user_id;
    alert(userID);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So if my alert() needs values from 2 references, would it be best to put the second on() in the callback of the first, and the alert() in the callback of the second?

Comment: That's the easiest way, but it'll be a little slower since you don't start the second request until the first is finished.  Ideally you'd start them both at once.  To do that, you'll need to do a little extra work to keep track of whether they've completed or not, and then in your callbacks do something like "if (/*both have completed and I haven't done my processing yet*/) { /* do my processing */ }"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a common methodology to wait on two callbacks, using using [jQuery's Promise model](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [once](http://www.firebase.com/docs/firebase/once.html):

```
var userID = 0;

// sends a callback to fx where the results can be stored
function defer( fx ) {
   return function() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      fx( function(snapshot) { deferred.resolve(snapshot.val(); } );
      return deferred.promise();
   }
}

$.when( // wait for both actions to complete
   defer( function(callback) { userRef.once('value', callback)   }),
   defer( function(callback) { widgetRef.once('value', callback) })
).then( function(values) {   
   // both deferreds are done now
   // and values contains an array with the snapshot.val() from each call
   console.log(values);
});
```